# Context switch from the app window and terminal in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

Which keyboard command can I use in order to switch between the application window, and terminal window in WebStorm?

I'm looking for a way to avoid using the mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>